# How to use flask login session

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask, flask-login

In my project, the client sends JSON data to receive processed data from the server.

The server receives that JSON data like so:

```
@app.route('/user/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    jsonString = urllib.unquote(request.data)
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonString)

    email = jsonData['email']
    password = jsonData['password']

    loginUser = userManager.login(email, password)

    if loginUser == False:
        return "False"
    else:
        session['email'] = loginUser.email
        session['name'] = loginUser.name
        return "True"
```

I don't use Jinja nor any other services which help connecting server and client.

The problem I have is that the client doesn't save cookies or the session. I learned that sessions are saved server-side, so how do I connect cookies (which have a session id) and how do I save cookies on the client (which can be connected with the server's sessions)?

Comment: Sessions being serverside isn't entirely true. In PHP it requires the client to save a cookie which contains a key identifying their current session that is sent to the server when they do something. The server looks up their session state with this. Flask's session probably does the same, so I'm not exactly sure what the issue is here. Did you try poking at this: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/